# lua equivalent of python repr

Tags: python, lua, repr

Is there an equivalent function to Python's repr() function in Lua? In other words a function that prints non-printable characters with \x where x is n or b etc, or \000 code if not a Lua string escape character. I've googled and can't find anything. Lots to find about putting non-printables in a string, nothing about generating a print-friendly version of a string with non-printable chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest equivalent would be the `%q` option for [`string.format`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.format).

> The `q` option formats a string between double quotes, using escape sequences when necessary to ensure that it can safely be read back by the Lua interpreter. For instance, the call
>
> ```
>  string.format('%q', 'a string with "quotes" and \n new line')
> ```
>
> may produce the string:
>
> ```
> "a string with \"quotes\" and \
>   new line"
> ```

You'll notice that new lines are not converted into the the character pair `\n`. If you would prefer that, try the following function:

```
function repr(str)
    return string.format("%q", str):gsub("\\\n", "\\n")
end
```